# How to convert Persian date string to Datetime format

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Based on the following code, when I receive the hijri (Persian) time string in the method and want to convert it to datetime, the format will be returned to the Gregorian format if I want the hijri (Persian) format to be datetime.

```
        public static DateTime Convert_String_To_DateTime(string PersianDate, string Time)
    {
        PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
        int year = Convert.ToInt32(PersianDate.Substring(0, PersianDate.IndexOf('/')));
        int month = Convert.ToInt32(PersianDate.Substring(PersianDate.IndexOf('/') + 1, 2));
        int day = Convert.ToInt32(PersianDate.Substring(PersianDate.IndexOf('/') + 4, 2));
        int hour = Convert.ToInt32(Time.Substring(0, Time.IndexOf(':')));
        int min = Convert.ToInt32(Time.Substring(Time.IndexOf(':') + 1));
        DateTime ConvertedDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, min, 0, pc);
        return ConvertedDate;
    }
```

Comment: DateTime does not have a format, use ToString and specify a culture to get back a formatted string for a specific culture.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you want to accomplish but if you want to change the output of your date and time you can use

```
 DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
 string mydate = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
```

dd - day
MM - Month short ex. for August you gonna get 08 if you want just 8 use single M and MMM for 3 letters and MMMM for a full month like August
yyyy - Year same rule applies to year as well
hh-Hour
mm-minute
ss secont
you have as well tt that will show you AM/PM

Comment: My database column format is data type and I can't register the string format in it.

Answer (score 0):

you use from   PersianCalendar  library  and you should solve your problem with this function in that library

```
 Datetime miladiconvert= PersianDateTime.Parse(Yourvariable).ToDateTime();
```

but you should pass currect format in this parsing so you should this funcation i wrote and use it

```
       public string convertdate(string date)
    {
        string[] st = new string[3];
        st = date.Split('/');
        if (int.Parse(st[0]) < 10)//year
        {
            st[0] = "0" + st[0];
        }
        if (int.Parse(st[1]) < 10 && st[1].Length == 1)//month
        {
            st[1] = "0" + st[1];
        }
        if (int.Parse(st[2]) < 10 && st[2].Length == 1)//day
        {
            st[2] = "0" + st[2];
        }
        date = st[0] + "/" + st[1] + "/" + st[2];
        return date;
    }
```

Finally if you want add hour and minutes you can use from add

```
miladiconvert= miladiconvert.AddHours(your Hours)
miladiconvert=miladiconvert.AddMinutes(your Minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `https://github.com/Mds92/MD.PersianDateTime`

Section `Parse` samples

```
var persianDateTime1 = PersianDateTime.Parse("دوشنبه 05 مرداد 1395 ساعت 04:03");
var persianDateTime2 = PersianDateTime.Parse(13901229); // تاریخ
var persianDateTime2 = PersianDateTime.Parse(13901229231232102); // تاریخ به همراه زمان تا دقت میلی ثانیه
var persianDateTime3 = PersianDateTime.Parse("چهارشنبه، ۱۰ دی ۱۳۹۳ ۱۲:۳۸");
var persianDateTime4 = PersianDateTime.Parse("24 آذر 1393");
var persianDateTime5 = PersianDateTime.Parse("د 24 آذر 1393 4:2:5:5 ب.ظ");
var persianDateTime6 = PersianDateTime.Parse("1393/02/01");
var persianDateTime7 = PersianDateTime.Parse("1393/02/01 02:03");
var persianDateTime8 = PersianDateTime.Parse("1393-02-01 02:03:10:30");
var persianDateTime9 = PersianDateTime.Parse("93-1-1 3:15 ب.ظ");
var persianDateTime10 = PersianDateTime.Parse("جمعه 93/2/1 ساعت 3:2 ب.ظ");
```

Result sample:

```
// ۱۳۹۹/۱۰/۰۳
Console.Write(persianDateTime1.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd"));
```